# Redirect to particular screen when click on remote push notification in react native (App is in background state)

Tags: push-notification, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-push-notification

I want to redirect to inbox screen after clicking on push notification on android and iOS

> Case 1: App already opened on android. - Successfully Working

Push notification received. On Clicking on notification page redirected to inbox successfully.

```
NOTIFICATION: {"dealer": "SWRoa0ZhSkN4Y2hQNW1NeWtFdHFvSDNlcXIyNnc1TG5PS1hOZjJoMElHST0=", "finish": [Function finish], "foreground": false, "id": "-1073464079", "message": "hello", "messagetype": "RESPONSE", "subject": "ENQUIRY RESPONSE", "title": “Sample 1”, "userInteraction": true}

PushNotification.configure({
  onNotification: function(notification) {
    console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
    console.log('NOTIFICATION CLICK STATE : --->' + notification.userInteraction);
    if(notification.userInteraction === true) {
        NavigationService.navigate('Inbox');
    }
  },
  popInitialNotification: true,
});
```

> Case 2: App running in background or closed on android - Failed

Push notification received. On clicking on notification page redirection not working, only app get opened.

No notification data received

> Case 3: On IOS in case of app opened or closed. - Failed

Push notification received. On clicking on notification page redirection not working, only app get opened.

No notification data received

I am using **react-native-push-notification library** for push notification.

```
https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification
```

Comment: Post your code that does the navigation part when a notification is received. The code that works for `Case 1`.

Comment: hi, please check question i have added code that works for Case 1. @AndreiOlar

Comment: Can you post more of the code where `PushNotification.configure({})` is called. I think we need a bit more context.

Comment: Another question: Do you see the console logs when tapping on the notification?

Comment: yes for case 1 i can see console log but for case 2 and 3 there is no console.

Comment: i am calling **PushNotification.configure({})** in App.js. Before class starts

Comment: Try to call it inside the `constructor` or `componentDidMount`. Does it make a difference?

Comment: that i have already tried . but no difference

Comment: I have a fully working published app where i have 2 different types of notification and i redirect user to different views based on this type, but I use **OneSignal** instead of react-native-push-notification, it's very easy to set up and works like a charm! Would you like to see how I handled this situation with a different library?

Comment: Did u and  any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it isn't good to promote other packages. However, I suggest looking into [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) will be good idea. It provides the feature to handle redirection even when the app is not on foreground.